# Replace even/odd occurrences of string in SQL SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I run this query on a SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT Coordinates 
FROM Table
```

And I get this result:

```
TextA,TextB,TextC,TextD,TextE,TextF
```

What I would like is to parse this result and get the following outcome:

```
TextA,TextB;TextC,TextD;TextE,TextF
```

That is, a semicolon after each pair.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What is linking your pair (X,Y)? Is there some kind of id that indicates that X and Y should be paired?

Comment: Thanks Jean for your prompt reply. X and Y are just text. I want to format the result so that every two commas found, one is replaced with a semicolon.

Comment: What sql-server? TSQL? PostGres?

Comment: There is no easy way to split your strings. You're going to need a function or something. Are you ok with a function itself?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this on the SQL side.  This kind of task is much easier using C# or another client side programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1: i just noticed a problem with last row of the result (it's also a X), trying to fix this now.

Edit 2: fixed the bug from edit 1

This query gets you a function which splits your inputstring like this result:

```
select * from dbo.Split('123,456,789,000', ',')

Nr  Typ  Value
1   X    123
1   Y    456
2   X    789
2   Y    000
```

Function-Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
    @InputString    VARCHAR(5000),
    @Delimiter      VARCHAR(50)
    )

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
        Nr      INT,
        Typ     VARCHAR(50),
        Value   VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

AS
BEGIN
    IF @Delimiter = ' '
    BEGIN
        SET @Delimiter = ','
        SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
    END

    IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
        SET @Delimiter = ','

        DECLARE @Item       VARCHAR(5000)
        DECLARE @ItemList   VARCHAR(5000)
        DECLARE @Typ        VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @DelimIndex INT
        DECLARE @RowNumber  INT

        SET @ItemList = @InputString
        SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
        SET @Typ = 'Y'      -- the typ for the coordinates, also the indicator for @RowNumber
        SET @RowNumber = 0  -- each pair gets their own rownumber

        WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            SET @Typ = (CASE WHEN @Typ = 'Y' THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END)
            SET @RowNumber = @RowNumber + (CASE WHEN @Typ = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@RowNumber, @Typ, @Item)

            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
        END

        IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- if at least 1 delimiter was encountered in @InputString
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@RowNumber + 1, (CASE WHEN @Typ = 'Y' THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END), @Item)
        END

        -- if 0 delimiters where found it just returns the default @InputString
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@RowNumber + 1, @Typ, @InputString)

        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

With a recursive CTE you can do this fast and easy:

```
WITH Tab AS(
    SELECT ID = 1
         , Coordinates = 'TexasdasdtA,TextB,TextC,TexsdsdstD,TextE,TextF'
         , AnotherCol = 'Bla'
),
ParseCoordinates AS(
    SELECT
          ID 
        , result    = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        , remaining = Tab.Coordinates
    FROM Tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
          ID 
        , result    = result +';'+ NextPart.Value
        , remaining = SUBSTRING(remaining, LEN(NextPart.Value)+2, LEN(remaining))
    FROM ParseCoordinates
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT Value = SUBSTRING(remaining, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',remaining, CHARINDEX(',',remaining)+1)-1, -1), LEN(remaining)))
        ) AS NextPart
    WHERE remaining <> ''
)
SELECT T.ID
     , Coordinates = SUBSTRING(result, 2, LEN(result))
     , AnotherCol
FROM Tab AS T
    INNER JOIN ParseCoordinates AS PS
        ON T.ID = PS.ID        
WHERE remaining = ''
```

**EDIT:** Depending on the number of column go for A) pass them all along through the CTE or B) pass only an key through the CTE and join original tab to the CTE with parsed values.

Comment: Everything is relative but i wouldn't know of an faster approach. You could do some micro optimizations on this query, some of which will hurt readability. An other approach would be using an scalar function which would be definitely slower. Using XML may be possible, might be faster. Doing it client side, as you suggested above, would definitely be faster. SQL Server sucks at string manipulations.

Comment: Nice read, conclusion: no CTE approach on long strings :)  as I said SQL Server sucks at string manipulations, so no surprise there.

Comment: Yeah, if you need to do some funky string work you really want a CLR

Comment: @Hogan Thank you for this approach. In my case, the number of rows isn't high, so performance is not an issue. What if besides column "Coordinates" I want to show other columns? Where should I put this? Tried adding this to the last SELECT outside the WITH's scope, but every row shows the same info. Should I use another temporary table for this?

Comment: @Gonzalo - MWillemse wrote this, please thank him.  To use on multiple columns you should make a function and then call it.  Maybe MWillemse will revise the answer to include that?

Comment: Sorry! I meant to tag @MWillemse. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will do something like what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Label varchar(20));

INSERT INTO TestTable (Label)
VALUES ('TextA'), ('TextB'), ('TextC'), ('TextD'), ('TextE'), ('TextF');

DECLARE @flag bit;
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX);
SET @flag = 0;
SET @result = ''; 
SELECT @result += Label + CASE WHEN @flag = 0 THEN ',' ELSE ';' END, @flag = ~@flag
FROM TestTable;
SELECT @result;
```

Comment: The question is not rows of data but a single field with `,`s in it that he wants to replace every 2nd one.

Comment: It occurs to me if you use one of the standard "SplitString()" functions available around StackOverflow to parse the comma-separated string into multiple rows, then this same algorithm can produce the desired results (just replace the FROM TestTable" to From dbo.SplitString(column value)... it'd be kind of awkward, but it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

Create this function to group Coordinates. The function has been adapted from [here](http://technolog.nl/blogs/eprogrammer/archive/2014/08/28/The-Ultimate-T_2D00_SQL-String-Splitter-_2800_function_2900_.aspx) and its functionality extend per your requirement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_CoordinatesGrouper] (
    @List VARCHAR(max)
    ,@delimiter VARCHAR(10)
    )
RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE (col VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Values TABLE (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
        ,col VARCHAR(8000)
        )

    IF @List IS NULL
        OR LEN(@List) = 0
        RETURN;

    SET @List = replace(@List, CHAR(39) + CHAR(39), CHAR(39))

    DECLARE @Index INT = 1;
    DECLARE @ItemValue VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @pos INT = 1;
    DECLARE @l INT = LEN(@List);

    WHILE @Index > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, @pos);

        IF @Index > 0
            IF (@index - @pos > 0)
                SET @ItemValue = SUBSTRING(@List, @pos, @index - @pos);
            ELSE
                SET @ItemValue = NULL;
        ELSE IF (@l - @pos + 1) > 0
            SET @ItemValue = SUBSTRING(@List, @pos, @l - @pos + 1);
        ELSE
            SET @ItemValue = NULL;

        INSERT INTO @Values (col)
        VALUES (@ItemValue);

        SET @pos = @index + 1;
    END;

    WITH cte_XAxis
    AS (
        SELECT id
            ,col
        FROM @Values
        WHERE id % 2 = 1
        )
        ,cte_YAxis
    AS (
        SELECT id
            ,col
        FROM @Values
        WHERE id % 2 = 0
        )
        --INSERT INTO @ReturnValue
        ,cte_Coordinates
    AS (
        SELECT xa.col + ISNULL(',' + ya.col, '') AS Coordinates
        FROM cte_XAxis xa
        LEFT JOIN cte_YAxis ya ON xa.ID = (ya.ID - 1)
        )
    INSERT INTO @ReturnValue
    SELECT STUFF((
                SELECT ';' + Coordinates
                FROM cte_Coordinates t2
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Usage

```
SELECT *
FROM [udf_CoordinatesGrouper]('TextA,TextB,TextC,TextD,TextE,TextF', ',')
GO
```